# What is "conjuga paria"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

In Sebastian Castellio [Gen. 6:19](https://books.google.com/books?id=1d5UAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA2-PA6&lpg=RA2-PA6&dq=coniuga%20paria&source=bl&ots=D-MH1KT-U1&sig=ACfU3U04pIDMoFzKSyPPLd--2SOoKaEqIA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCyrSI2djwAhUPkhQKHamZBBYQ6AEwBnoECAsQAw#v=onepage&q=coniuga%20paria&f=false)

> Eodem etiam de omnibus vita praeditis corporibus **coniuga paria** inferes, ut tecum in vita supersint. (you will bring there also *coniuga paria* from all living creatures, so that they live with you)

I believe *paria* is to mean *couples* (n; pl. acc.), but I'm not sure of *conjuga*. according to the dictionaries it seems to be another female form of *conjunx*, but it doesn't fit here.

Comment: Gaffiot gives "conjŭgus, a, um (conjugo), qu’on peut joindre : PRISC. Gramm. 17, 60" (i.e., joinable). Georges also gives this meaning but [also says](http://www.zeno.org/Georges-1913/A/coniugus): "= σύζυγος (Apoll. de synt. p. 100, 21 B.)" (whatever that cryptic incantation means), for which [see here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/σύζυγος) (but that pertains to modern Greek).

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in comment by Sebastian Koppehel, According to [Georges](http://www.zeno.org/Georges-1913/A/coniugus) the adjective *conjugus* means σύζυγος. This ancient-Greek adjective (a noun in modern Greek) is rendered by Thayer's Greek Lexicon as [follows](https://biblehub.com/greek/4805.htm):

> yoked together; used by Greek writers (from Aeschylus down) of those united by the bond of marriage, relationship, office, labor, study, business, or the like; hence, a yoke-fellow, consort, comrade, colleague, partner.

*par* can be used substantively to mean a *pair*. This *pair* however does not necessary pertain to a couple in marriage (e.g. *par oculorum*). So, in this context of animals, the term **paria conjuga** means, as excepted, pairs of animals each consists of male and female.